# JavaFX Spinner units

Tags: javafx, format, spinner

I would like to set a units to a spinner which is accepting only numbers.
Ideally the spinner textfield would display the units right next to the number itself (example: 2500 ms or 125 % etc.).

Is there a way to set a format to the textfield?

I thought it would be fairly easy but I can't find a way.

Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner value factory has a [`converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.html#converterProperty) that is used to convert the value to and from the text value displayed or entered in the editor. You can use this to configure how the value is displayed:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class SpinnerWithUnits extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>();
        spinner.setEditable(true);

        SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 10000, 0, 100);

        valueFactory.setConverter(new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer value) {
                return value.toString()+" ms";
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                String valueWithoutUnits = string.replaceAll("ms", "").trim();
                if (valueWithoutUnits.isEmpty()) {
                    return 0 ;
                } else {
                    return Integer.valueOf(valueWithoutUnits);
                }
            }

        });

        spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(spinner);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Of course, you probably want to use a more appropriate type than `Integer` as the type of the spinner: in this case it would probably make more sense to use a `Duration`. You can still use a converter on the (now custom) spinner value factory to display the value formatted as you need.